# Add properties to Google Datastore entity dynamically

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a below use case:

I have a method that accepts a list of strings. For each of the strings, I need to create a property under an existing google data store entity `A`

**Example:** I have an existing entity `Person` with properties `fname` and `lname`.
If the input list has strings - `address`, `city`, I need to update the entity `Person` to include these new properties `address` and `city`.

I'm coding this use case in Python. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the best way to do this is to let your class inherit [`ndb.Expando`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entity-models#creating_an_expando_model_class). The difference between `Expando` and `Model` is that you can always add attributes to an `Expando` entity and be able to store it in the Datastore.

Knowing this, there are several ways to proceed, but I am guessing you’re also going to need to use Python’s `setattr(object, name, value)` method to pass the attribute name from a string.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Expando model class: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entity-models#creating_an_expando_model_class

```
class Person(ndb.Expando):
    pass

person = Person(fname='some', lname='body')
person_key = person.put()

...

person = person_key.get()
person.city = 'San Francisco'
person.address = '1234 Main St.'
person.put()
```